# Restrict Regex to be 8 to 15 characters long

Tags: regex

I have the following regex checking password complexity.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])){8,15}.+$
```

1. At least one lowercase
2. At least one Uppercase
3. At least one Symb0l
4. At least 1 number

But I also want to restrict it to only allow all the above plus length. Valid length would be anything between 8 and 15.

I've tried doing that by adding the `{8,15}`, but that doesn't seem to work! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misplaced the quantifier:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_\W]).{8,15}$
                                           ^^^^^^
```

Also, `(_|[^\w])` is the same as `[_\W]`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qljNPr/2).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*\d)` - at least 1  digit
- `(?=.*[_\W])` -  at least 1 "special", non-alphanumeric, char
- `.{8,15}` - any 8 to 15 chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have anything else to do but answer regex questions within 2 minutes they are published?

Comment: At this point every regex tag should be directly sent to him. I saw no one else on SO answering these type of questions as fast as @WiktorStribiżew does.

Comment: Really? Then this should be really important!

Comment: I'm sure the folks who post questions do not expect to get the answer within seconds. Fast is (almost) irrelevant.